# How can I select a char from a string inside a list in python and compare it with a single char?

Tags: python, string, list, char

Here is the code where I try to take the "t" char from the "two" string from the li list and compare it to a single "t" char:

```
li=["one","two","three"];

choice=1;

if li[choice[1]]=="t":
    print("valid");

else:
    print("unvalid");
```

The problem is that when I run it, it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yobob\Documents\cours\ISN\ProjetISN\testPython.py", line 3, in <module>
    if li[choice[1]]=="t":
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`choice[1]` is doing `1[1]` which doesn't make sense. I think you want `li[choice][1]`. i.e.

```
if li[choice][1] == "t":
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! (the [1] next to choice purpose was to select the first char but It needed to be next to the whole array like this: li[choice][1])